# line break within table column

Tags: tables

I have looked up many of the previous posts on this....but of no avail.....I need a solution to break a line within a table column, without a break appearing at the table edge of the second row....my table has only two rows....is there a way to do this?

for instance

```
\begin{table}[H]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{| c | p{3cm} |}

\hline

\textbf{Equation} & \textbf{Description} \\

\hline

eq1\\ eq2 & "some text" \\\hline

\hline
```

Now because of the `\\` between `eq1` and `eq2`, a break occurs in the line bordering the table after "some text". I need a workaround to avoid the table breaking at the end of the second row. The method `eq1\\\ eq2` does shift `eq2` to a new line within the same column, which is what I want, but without the side effect of the right border to the second row breaking at the same point. In other words, the splitting into two lines should be confined within the same column, without impacting the row.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` inside a `tabular`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mysplit}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}   %% remove [t] if you need vertical centered things.
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{| c | p{3cm} |}
  \hline
  \textbf{Equation} & \textbf{Description} \\
  \hline
  \mysplit{eq1\\ eq2} & ``some text'' \\\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed

"some text" to ``some text''

[H] to [htb]

as they are the recommended ways.

[image]

Further it is better to get rid of vertical lines and use `booktabs` for drawing rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\mysplit}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}   %% removed [t]
    #1
  \end{tabular}
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ c  p{3cm} }
  \toprule
  \textbf{Equation} & \textbf{Description} \\
  \midrule
  \mysplit{eq1\\ eq2} & ``some text'' \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details a some tutorial please the `booktabs` manual which you can get by running `texdoc booktabs` from command prompt or in the texdoc help menu of your tex editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that  most easily with the `makecell` package, which allows for linebreaks and a common formatting in cells, with the `\thead` and `\makecell` commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs, mathtools}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c p{3cm}}
\toprule
\textbf{Equation} & \textbf{Description} \\
\midrule
\makecell{ eq1\\ eq2 } & "some text" \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]